# Meteor not publishing correct users

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to publish a list of users. I'm checking a collection for `accoutActive: true` and then fetching the `studentUserId`. I thought I could then use this to find the meteor.user however it returns nothing. Could someone please tell me what I'm missing.

```
Meteor.publish('list', function() {
  var activeStudent = StudentAccountStatus.find(
                          {"accountActive": true},
                          {fields:
                            {"studentUserId": 1}
                          }
                        ).fetch();

  return Meteor.users.find(
                    {_id: activeStudent}
                  );
});
```

Comment: I don't get why you are not directly returning your first query. Remove the .fetch() as you need to return a Mongo cursor on publish function.

Comment: The `activeStudent` is assigned an array of objects. You need to recover the relevant string out of it (or an array of strings and use an `$in` selector). Note that the result will not be reactive (in the sense that additional "active" accounts won't be published) and be very careful about the user fields that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your activeStudent variable contains an array of objects which would look something like this:

```
[ { _id: 'a104259adsjf' },
  { _id: 'eawor7u98faj' },
... ]
```

whereas for your mongo query you just need an array of strings, i.e. `['a104259adsjf', 'eawor7u98faj', ...]`.

So, you need to iterate through your array of objects to construct the array of strings, like with the lodash _.map function:

```
var activeStudentIds = _.map(activeStudent, function(obj) {
    return obj._id;
});
```

Then, using the mongo $in selector you can reformulate your query as:

```
return Meteor.users.find(
    {_id: { $in: activeStudentIds } }
);
```